# google cloud storage make object public through python Firebase admin SDK

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-admin

I'm trying to make an excel file I upload to Firebase storage (google cloud storage) publicly available as a link. When I use the method `blob.make_public()` I get a Forbidden 403 error: Insufficient permission.

I'm using the Firebase Admin SDK for python. As far as I can tell in the IAM part of the cloud console the admin SDK has Editor and Storage Object Admin roles. Any way to make the uploaded object public through python?

Haven't found anything else that works in the docs:
[Python GCS API](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/blobs.html)

Thanks.

Code example

```
# Access google cloud storage bucket
bucket = firebase_admin.storage.bucket(app=app)
# Blob - Google's wrapper for objects stored in buckets
destination_blob_name = 'excelReports/' + filename + '_' + datetime.now().strftime("%b_%d_%Y_%H_%M_%S")
blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)

# Upload file
blob.upload_from_filename(filename)

# Make the file available for public download by those who have the link.
blob.make_public()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried the following integration test case, and it worked as expected.

```
from firebase_admin import storage

def test_make_public(project_id):
    bucket_name = '{0}.appspot.com'.format(project_id)
    bucket = storage.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob('data/dinosaurs.json')
    blob.upload_from_filename('tests/data/dinosaurs.json')
    blob.make_public()
```

After the test I could find the `data/dinosaurs.json` file in the GCS bucket, marked as public.

Make sure you're using the correct service account file to initialize the Admin SDK. And also ensure the bucket you're trying to access belongs to the same Firebase project as the credential. Also ensure that your file upload completes successfully -- i.e. the file actually ends up in the intended location.

Comment: It's the service account .json file I got through the Firebase console for this project and is listed in the project IAM Members list. Is there a different route to get the service account file? The bucket is in the same project and the file does upload correctly in the intended location. Still fails on `blob.make_public()` Will try getting a new credential file, but this one does let me access the database and make uploads.

Comment: New service account credential file made through the IAM interface did not help. Still permission denied.

Comment: I wonder if your bucket has some unusual permissions. Might be useful to check the bucket permissions. In my set up, the bucket has "Storage Legacy Bucket Owner" permissions to my service account.

Comment: So it works this morning without really making any changes to upload code, permissions, or service account file. The only thing I can think of is I was fixing a pandas error and made sure it was running in the correct virtual environment. The main environment had older firebase-admin and google-cloud-storage package versions. I'm just guessing here. Thank you for your help.